# Firebase Phone Number Authentication DigitsLike

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Months ago, I implemented Digits phone number verification on the mobile app and verified the oAuth headers sent from the again from the backend to make sure that the phone number already verified his identity.

I was calling api.digits.com while sending the consumer key and the oauth etc.., 
as I read in firebase, the user can automatically sign in with the phone number.

I read that the user can add his id and number to firebase database after being verified, but this does not mean that he has passed the phone number verification if he bypassed the verification step in any way.

Is there any way to check that the user is really logged in with oauth credentials from my backend? Or there is any alternative?

Comment: you should try this. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913105/token-mismatch-using-phone-number-authentication-ios/53914196#53914196)