# Token Mismatch using Phone Number Authentication - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication, token

I am trying to login account using phone number authentication using firebase.

Initially, i deployed the app with my device and it works fine. But when i tried to deploy app to another device and then it throws me error `Token Mismatch`.

I have searched several answers in `stackoverflow` and then i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490693/firebase-sms-verification-on-ios-token-mismatch) and i followed but it didn't work for me.

I have checked following :

1. Ensure I had both a valid development and production APNS certificate uploaded to the Firebase Dashboard, under 'Project Settings' > 'Cloud Messaging'. (My APNS certificate is valid till next year).
2. In Xcode, in the .entitlements file, make sure the APS Environment value is set to either 'development' or 'production', depending on your testing situation. (I also checked).
3. Finally (this is what I was missing), check inside your AppDelegate.swift and inside the method for `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, change the value from `.sandbox` to `.prod`, or to `.unknown` to let the app bundle determine which token type to use, based on your provisioning profile.

This 3rd i also changed

```
    let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print("==== This is device token ",token)
    let data = Data(token.utf8)
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(data, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
```

But still when i run this app on another device which it always throws me that error.

But when i comment this line of code `// Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(data, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)` and then i run the app after that i uncomment that line of code `Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(data, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)` and then i run the app again and finally it works. But sadly, when i run another iOS device it still gives me error.
I wonder why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow steps

1) Import Firebase and FirebaseAuth

`import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth`

2) In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Configure firebase.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

3) Write these two func in AppDelegate.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
        print(userInfo)
        return
    }
}
```

4) In your ViewController class, repeat step **first** and write code for send OTP on Mobile Number, which you want.

```
@IBAction func sendCodeAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let ugrMgr = UserManager.userManager
    let phoneNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.phoneNumber
    print(phoneNumber!)
    print(ugrMgr.mobile!)
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber("+91" + ugrMgr.mobile!, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            mainInstance.ShowAlertWithError(error.localizedDescription as NSString, msg: error.localizedDescription as NSString)
            return
        }
    self.verificationID = verificationID

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks boss, it is working , main thing we need to set AuthAPNSTokenType. this value properly. it saved me lot time.

Comment: You can set the token type to unknown. The actual token type will be detected from the provisioning profile in the app's bundle.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure you set FirebaseApp.configure() in AppDelegate.swift

```swift
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure() 
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
```

2. Set the APNS token type to AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown. The actual token type will be detected from the provisioning profile in the app’s bundle.

```swift
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
    }
```

3. Change the aps-environment value from "development" to "unknown" in your Runner.entitlements file

[image: Runner.entitlements]